# Invalid datatype while calling a procedure from java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have 2 database procedures..
I am taking the output from one procedure in java and passing the output as an input to another procedure..

However, it is giving an invalid datatype error while passing the input to the 2nd procedure..Below is the definition of the first procedure from which Output is being taken..

```
PROCEDURE GET_PROJECT_DATA_PRC(PI_USER IN VARCHAR2,
PI_PROJECT_NO IN VARCHAR2,
PI_INVOICE_NUMBER IN NUMBER,
PO_PROJECT_EC_HEADER_DATA OUT TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE,
PO_PROJECT_EC_DETAIL_DATA OUT TAB_TRX_LINE_TYPE,
PO_PROJECT_LC_HEADER_DATA OUT TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE,
PO_PROJECT_LC_DETAIL_DATA OUT TAB_TRX_LINE_TYPE,
PO_PROJECT_PT_HEADER_DATA OUT TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE,
PO_PROJECT_PT_DETAIL_DATA OT TAB_TRX_LINE_TYPE,
PO_ERROR_CODE OUT NUMBER,
PO_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2)
```

Below is the java code which calls the above procedure and takes the output..

```
Call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
Call.withCatalogName(“INV_AR_INVOCING_PKG1”);
Call.withProcedureName(“GET_PROJECT_DATA_PRC”);
Call.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(“PI_USER”,OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
Call.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(“PI_PROJECT_NO”,OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
Call.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(“PI_INVOICE_NUMBER”,OracleTypes.NUMBER));
Call.addDeclaredParameter(new      SqlParameter(“PO_PROJECT_EC_HEADER_DATA”,OracleTypes.ARRAY,”TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE”,new  SqlReturnType() { public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,Int  sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException { Connection connection = cs.getConnection();
Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = connection.getTypeMap();
typeMap.put(“TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE”, InvoiceReviewErrorDto.class);
oracle.sql.ARRAY oraArray = (oracle.sql.ARRAY) ((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array)     ((CallableStatement) cs ).getObject( paramIndex )).unwrap(ARRAY.class);
return oraArray;
}
}))
.
.
.
.
Args = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
Args.put(“PI_EC_HEADER”, out.get(“PO_PROJECT_EC_HEADER_DATA”));
Args.put(“PI_EC_LINE”, out.get(“PO_PROJECT_EC_DETAIL_DATA”));
```

The definition of the second proc is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE INV_MAIN_PRC(PI_EC_HEADER IN TAB_TRX_HEADER_TYPE,
PI_EC_LINE IN TAB_TRX_LINE_TYPE,
PO_EC_CUST_TRX_ID OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID%TYPE,
PO_EC_AR_INV_NO OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.TRX_NUMBER%TYPE,
PO_LC_CUST_TRX_ID OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID%TYPE,
PO_LC_AR_INV_NO OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.TRX_NUMBER%TYPE,
PO_PT_CUST_TRX_ID OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID%TYPE,
PO_PT_AR_INV_NO OUT RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.TRX_NUMBER%TYPE,
PO_ERROR_CODE OUT NUMBER,
PO_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2);
```

The code for calling the 2nd proc is as below:

```
This.call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSourceGross).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
.withCatalogName(“INV_AR_INVOICE_PKG”)
.withProcedureName(“INV_MAIN_PRC”)
.declareParameters(
New SqlParameter(“PI_EC_HEADER”,OracleTypes.ARRAY),
New SqlParameter(“PI_EC_LINE”,OracleTypes.ARRAY),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_EC_CUST_TRX_ID”, OracleTypes.NUMBER),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_EC_AR_INV_NO”, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_LC_CUST_TRX_ID”, OracleTypes.NUMBER),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_LC_AR_INV_NO”, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_PT_CUST_TRX_ID”, OracleTypes.NUMBER),
New SqlOutParameter(“PO_PT_AR_INV_NO”, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
New SqlOutParameter(DBConstants.PO_ERROR_CODE,OracleTypes.NUMBER),
New SqlOutParameter DBConstants.PO_ERROR_MSG, OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
Out = call.execute(args);
```

The Exception message is as follows:
org.springfamework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call INV_AR_INVOICE_PKG.INV_MAIN_PRC(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

And the Stack trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL     grammar [{call INV_AR_INVOICE_PKG.INV_MAIN_PRC(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype at      org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubc    lassTranslator.java:94)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:373)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:177)
at com.ultimatix.dao.InvoiceReviewDAOImpl.invoicePreApprove(InvoiceReviewDAOImpl.java:678)
at com.ultimatix.service.InvoiceReviewServiceImpl.invoiceApprove(InvoiceReviewServiceImpl.java:518)
at com.ultimatix.controller.InvoiceReviewController.invoiceApprove(InvoiceReviewController.java:241)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at com.utxfrmwk.security.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.utxfrmwk.security.filter.SecurityInterceptor.doFilter(SecurityInterceptor.java:40)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1006)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3677)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:99)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1066)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1014)
```

Comment: Post the actual exception message and stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
I have edited the post to include the exception message and stack trace..kindly check